# Does topological equivalence of compact metric spaces imply strong equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In general [topological equivalence of metric spaces does not imply strong equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123503/does-topological-equivalence-of-metrics-imply-strong-equivalence). Is it true if the metric space is compact? More specifically: Let $d$ and $d'$ be topologically equivalent metrics on $X$. Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Are $d$ and $d'$ strongly equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d'(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$.
Since the open $r$-balls of one metric are the open $\sqrt r$ or $r²$ balls of the other, these metrics are weakly equivalent. But they are not strongly equivalent because $\frac {\sqrt r}r\to 0$ as $r\to 0$.